# How do I beat these trolls?

Tags: magic, warfare, space

Alright so I'm working on a story where trolls, armed with troll logic and advanced weaponry, are attacking the three main civilizations in the galaxy(for the second time). Earth, of course, has no idea this is going on but that's besides the point. The three civilizations have been living together for a while, have boundaries set up, and stuff like that. The three groups are the techies, maggies, and normies. Each keeps their technology level to themselves, and each play an important role in inter-galactic warfare.

**The techies**

> There's the techies, we have lots of the futuristic guns and spacecraft, we take care of a lot of the space battles and logistical issues like transportation.

The techies are basically the galactic empire, minus the death star and desire to control everything with people in white armor. They do a lot of transporting and do all the space fights. Sometimes they'll land a craft and set up artillery units on the ground but prefer to stay out in space. Most of their space craft has light speed travel, and some of their more advanced ones have FTL travel. About three techies for one maggy.

**The normies**

> The normies are what you have on this world, lots of soldiers lacking tech but making up for it with numbers and training, they do a lot of the assaults where our big guns are too big.

The normies make up all the main corp, everything from tanks to fighter jets to foot soldiers. Of course, they are spread across several worlds and have tech levels ranging from WWI to present day weaponry. Probably about three times as many normies as there are techies.

**The maggies**

> Then there's the maggies, not as many of them as the rest of us but very powerful, you guys were used for small infiltration missions or as shock troops.

The maggies are mages, casting spells and blowing stuff up. However, there were a lot less maggies than normies and techies, so are spread rather thin and are very valuable. They do a lot of infiltration missions or act as shock troops. One maggy could probably take out a few squads of normies or bring down a small techie space craft.

**The trolls**

> We were fighting against the trolls, a race of short ugly people who used twisted logic to build extremely dangerous weaponry only they could use.

Lots of these guys, all short and ugly but also with spacecraft and deadly weaponry the techies don't understand. These are the bad guys, attacking worlds and taking over stuff because they feel like it. Trolls have land, air, and space craft at their disposal and have already set up a base in the galaxy from which to launch attacks from.

**The problem**

On their own, each of the three civilizations don't have a very good chance at beating the trolls, but have already banded together and are trying to stop the trolls. However, the maggies are currently otherwise occupied until their leader can lead them. Until the maggies get into the fight, the normies and techies have to keep the trolls back. Without maggies, however, the biggest weapon the techies have won't do much. The trolls already lost once and can counter everything the techies currently have. The trolls however are able to destroy techie craft like a pinata, and all that candy inside is rather expensive to replace.

Until the maggies decide to join the fight, the techies and normies are getting beat up trying to stop the trolls, so they need a new strategy. How can the techies and normies stop or at least stall the trolls?

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. Please remember, worldbuilding (on-topic) is about helping you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of a fictional world of your own design. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances, plot, and character choices/actions. The problem is that all storybuilding is opinion-based by definition and there's no way for you to objectively select a best answer. (See [help/dont-ask] where it states to not ask questions were every answer is equally valid.)

Comment: "however, the biggest weapon the techies have won't do much" -- But they have lightspeed engines. Are you saying that attaching a lightspeed engine to an asteroid, pointing it at the enemy, and turning it on "won't do much?"

Answer (score 1):

To put it in a worldbuilding frame, one might build the trolls main weakness into their racial psychology.  And I would suggest that in a troll this is greed.

If you really build up their space gluttony, I think you create an interesting cultural element, as well as showing how they do so well in conquering, and how it can be used against them by the "good guys."

Answer (score 1):

#### You've basically created WW1 trench warfare in space.

You have two sides with both large numbers and powerful weapons. A direct attack is going to be suicide for either side.

So no action is needed to delay the war until deus ex machina, both sides will take heavy losses in a few frontal attacks until they dig in in favourable orbits, asteroid belts, or just patrolling around conquered space.

Both sides will end up advancing your forces to just out range of either other, leaving a no mans land between your two forces. This will probably end up mined by both techies and trolls.

Mages will come in and save the day, this is comparable to tanks being introduced and allowing the quagmire to be broken.

The actual flow of battle is getting into story-based stuff beyond the scope of world building - but I think the simile of your battle to WW1 warfare may help with this.